# How to save excel file on android which is built using kivy app?

Tags: python, android, kivy, xlsxwriter

Can anyone help me with this please...I'm new to kivy and I had developed an app using python's kivy framework. In which I had used xlsxwriter for creating excel file. But the perplexing thing is when I run it on my windows that excel file is created and gets automatically saves down into the local python containing folder in the name which I give it as an text input. But unfortunately when I built it as an app using buildozer through google colab its not working. I mean the app is working but when I click on the save button then nothing happens. I had searched for the excel file in all over my file browser of my mobile. But its no where...

Can anyone help me to solve this issue. And **thanks in advance**...

Here's the 'main.py' python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix import label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import xlsxwriter


class Boxlayoutexam(BoxLayout):
    my_text=StringProperty('Data Acquisition to be started')
    def on_button_click(self):
        self.my_text='Data Acquisition started'


class StartPopup(Popup):
    def on_yes_button_click(self):
        my_textinput = self.ids.my_textinput.text

        workbook= xlsxwriter.Workbook(my_textinput+'xlsx')
        worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet('Diabetic Data')
        workbook.close()


class myapp(App):
    pass

myapp().run()
```

And here's the 'myapp'.kv kivy file:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
Boxlayoutexam:

<YesPopup@Popup>:
    auto_dismiss: True
    title: 'FILE SAVED'
    size_hint:0.6,0.6
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Image:
            source: "greentick.png"
            allow_stretch: True
            size_hint:1.0,0.7
        Label:
            text: 'YOUR FILE GOT SAVED!'
            font_size: 24
            size_hint:1.0,0.3



<StartPopup@Popup>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'SAVE THE FILE'
    size_hint:0.6,0.6

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text:'Do you want to save the file?'
            font_size: 24
            size_hint:1.0,0.5

        TextInput:
            id: my_textinput
            size_hint:1.0,1.0
            font_size: 30
            multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text:'YES'
                font_size: 24
                size_hint:1.0,1.0
                on_press: Factory.YesPopup().open()
                on_press: root.on_yes_button_click()

            Button:
                text:'NO'
                font_size: 24
                size_hint:1.0,1.0
                on_release: root.dismiss()

<Boxlayoutexam>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    Label:
        text:'Real time data acquistion'
        size_hint:1.0,0.8

    Label:
        text:root.my_text
        size_hint:1.0,0.1
    Button:
        text:'START'
        font_size:30
        size_hint:1.0,0.2
        on_press:root.on_button_click()
        on_release: Factory.StartPopup().open()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For providing path to save here's a minimal reproducible example

```
import xlsxwriter
work = xlsxwriter.Workbook('//storage//emulated//0//one.xlsx')
work.add_worksheet()
work.close()
```

And to add

```
MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Line 96 in buildozer spec

```
android.permissions = MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: Mr. Aditya thakker, thanks for your time and patient answering. I had followed the same steps as you told. But the things haven't went as we thought. It should have created a excel file in the name of 'one.xlsx' but it haven't. Instead It just closes the app once when I press the button and I had searched all over the phone directory and the file is nowhere found...

Comment: Did you grant the permission, cause even after adding it to requirements you have to grant them. Try getting the logcat using `adb logcat | findstr com.example.app`

Comment: Hello Aditya thakker, thanks for your consistent help in this thread. I had run the logcat as you said and found that tells like this...
12-14 18:03:21.975 23251 23275 I python  :  xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '//storage//emulated//0//one.xlsx'
12-14 18:03:21.975 23251 23275 I python  : Python for android ended.
I can post the whole logcat if you wish and thanks in advance

Comment: There you go, there you have your error and as I said it's permission not granted `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '//storage//emulated//0//one.xlsx`, do just one thing, go to your app info and then the permissions and then grant the permissions that's it and your app should work like charm

Comment: Mr Aditya thakker, 
thankyou thank you so much…It works and it got saved in the phone’s storage folder. You are a gentleman and a scholar and such a life saver…

Comment: To put cherry on top you could create a folder to store all xlsx in one folder using the os library

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a path set for output which would mean that this file may be saved in app private directory,thus it would be inaccessible for you.

The path that you need to provide:

```
/storage/emulated/0/the folder where you want to save xlsx
```

/storage/emulated/0 is universally accepted path on android phones

Do remember to add storage permission in buildozer.spec and use permission

```
MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: Hello Aditya thakker, thankyou so much for the reply...But can you please elaborate or suggest how to give the directory and permissions in python and buildozer spec files

Comment: I'll add an answer to step by step guide